# can parent window be notified when the hotkey control content changed? (win32)

Tags: winapi, hotkeys

I create a window for use setting, it contains a hotkey control and an apply button. In normal way, the button is gray, but I want it be usable when the user set an new hotkey in the hotkey control.

I read the relation content in MSDN, but it seems hotkey control doesn't notify its parent window if the hotkey changed.

I don't want to query the hotkey (and compare with the original value) every 0.5 second.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does notify the parent window - via an EN_CHANGE notification in the WM_COMMAND message.  The MSDN documentation says as much:

[Hot Key Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775233.aspx):

> Hot Key Control Notifications
>
> The hot key control does not send any
>   notification messages via the
>   `WM_NOTIFY` message. It will, however,
>   send the `EN_CHANGE` notification via
>   the `WM_COMMAND` message when the user
>   changes the contents of the control.